# Insert React JS-JSX inside J2EE application

Tags: reactjs, tomcat, jsx

My objective is to add new UI screens based on React JS on an existing (JSP based) J2EE application running on local tomcat server. Yes, the ask is to add new screens using modern javascript/clientside technologies, but to retain the existing screens as it is.

I downloaded individual react.js and react-dom.js, added them to my J2EE project content, referenced them to the html page.  In this way(Without having to install node JS or setup react dev environment), i'm able to achieve my objective, but i could use only plain javascript React.createElement to create the UI components.

But, i would also need to use the JSX syntax to speed up my developments. Now, to use JSX features, i learned that i had to do setup of Node JS, Babel, etc and have to build the application. This will not fit to my objective, as i don't need a standalone React application, but only need to create additional screens based on react to existing J2EE application.

So, I need experts recommendations to accomplish this. My questions are

1. If i setup the react+babel development environment and build an app, can i get the transcompiled JS files easily, so that i can take them and deploy to my tomcat server?
2. If so, is this the only way to achieve my objective OR is there a better alternative for quicker development?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need expert recommendations its easy.

1) You can use create react app from create react app boiler plate from Facebook which gives everything from out of box.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

2) React app needs a div to load js.

```
Keep generated js bundle from above step in J2EE application and load script on JSP page using script tags.

<script src="/reactbundle.js"></script>

<div id="root"> </div>  // create this div in existing J2EE application in HTML or JSP file.

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root')
);
```